# Use command line cURL to post contents of file

Tags: curl

I am trying to use `cURL` to post data to a URL.  The URL is expecting a `<form>` submission and the `<textarea>` field with a specified value.  I have the value stored in a text file and I want to run `cURL` to post the contents of the data in the file to the web page.  This is what I have - however I do not think I am correctly escaping the file location:

```
curl -data info='@filename.txt' https://file.com/test > tmp.txt
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the man page, the correct syntax for sending the contents of a file as a POST variable is:

```
curl --data-urlencode 'info@filename.txt' https://file.com/test > tmp.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, unfortunately it did not work as expected.  Two observations: (1) - info is the name of the form element, according to the man page it should be:  cURL -data info='value', in the value field I want the contents of my filename.txt to be dumped in as the value.

Comment: That's exactly what --data-urlencode should do when used as field@filename, and in my tests it worked.